# Unity WebGL throwing Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: spring-boot, unity-game-engine, webassembly, unity-webgl

I'm currently experiencing this error trying to run a Unity WebGL (2018.2.11) module in a java web application running on Spring Boot (1.5.4). I tried all possible settings on Unity and on the web server as well, always getting the same result while it's loading:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.md5 (UnityLoader.js:3)
    at processWasmCodeJob (UnityLoader.js:4)
    at a.callback (UnityLoader.js:3)`

Here are the settings selected in Unity 2018.2.11f1:
[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show me your build other setting and publishing setting in Player Settings??

Comment: Can you also show us `UnityLoader.js`? or specific lines of codes where errors are coming.

Comment: As I said, I've tried every possible combination, so it doesn't make sense to show you the settings. UnityLoader.js is minified so I can't show you exactly where it happens.

Comment: Okay. try this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined-unityloader-js-1.470671/.

Comment: I've been on that page before, nothing useful there...

Comment: Try to unminify js, there's tools for that online. Then show us what line the error is happening on.

Comment: make a development build and get the idea where is error occurring.

Comment: Testing with a development build caused a completely different error. Didn't help.

Comment: looks like a faulty minified version